# Cognos Analytics 11

Tags: logging, cognos, cognos-bi, log-viewer

I'm trying to read logs in Cognos Analytics 11.0.7 and prior there was a logviewerv2 that made reading logs very simple. I read in a form that in version 11.0.6, IBM removed this feature.

I was hoping to get confirmation on this, and if there are any features similar to this in the newer versions for reading logs.

I have tried to find version notes on the updates but can't seem to find anything about removing or changing or even a mention of the logviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try IBM Cognos Exploration Tool for Event Analysis ([ICETEA](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=0ad1d51b-4366-4735-a999-3522a4cba6cd)), but IBM Support says the logs are for them, not for us.

Comment: Thanks for the response!